# [Study EJB]: annotation type is not applicable to this kind of declaration?

Tags: java, netbeans, annotations, ejb

Trying to create the simplest `EJB` using **NetBeans 7.0** and **EJB 3 in Action** book.

Well, firstly I've created an interface:

```
package study;

public interface NewInterface {
    public void sayHello(String name);
}
```

Then, the EJB:

```
package study;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

public class NewClass implements NewInterface{

    @Override
    @Stateless //! ERROR here !
    public void sayHello(String name) {
       System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }  
}
```

Java complains at `@Stateless`

> annotation type is not applicable to this kind of declaration

Why?

Comment: this annotation is used for class and not for methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be on the class declaration (not the method). Like so :

```
package study;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class NewClass implements NewInterface{

    @Override
    public void sayHello(String name) {
       System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }  
}
```

From [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/ejb30/annotations.html#wp1417411)